# Why does the macro gives compile error without any logical or syntax error in script?

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I wrote a macro in excel vba. I am attaching the script below. I don't see any logical or syntax error in the macro but when I try to compile it, I get `Compile error: Expected: To`

[image: Error]

Below is my script attached

```
Sub Go()

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Range("D:D").ClearContents
ws.Range("D:D").ClearFormats

ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Status"
ws.Cells(1, 4).Font.Bold = True

maxEntry = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, "A").End(xlUp).Row

pricePath = ws.Cells(2, 6).Value + "\" + ws.Cells(2, 7).Value
Set wbpp = Workbooks.Open(pricePath, UpdateLinks:=False)

ws.Activate

For i = 2 To maxEntry
    Path = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value + "\" + ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    currSheet = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Set wbp = Workbooks.Open(Path, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Set wbs = wbp.Sheets(currSheet)
    wbs.Activate
    wbs.Cells(1, 1).Value = "abc"

    wbp.Close Savechanges:=True
    ws.Activate
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Updated"
Next i

wbpp.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

After trying out various things I found out that the macro throws an error when my cursor is inside the macro sub, something like this

[image: Cursor in the Sub]

But when my cursor is outside the sub, the script runs fine

[image: Out of Sub]

[image: Run Box]

I don't remember this issue happening with my previous macros.

Any ideas why this is happening? Its really annoying to move cursor to the bottom to run every time I want to test/compile.

Comment: I tested a small code like this `Sub Go()
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Activate
End Sub
` and it worked. I could not reproduce your issue. My suggestion is change routine name from `Go` to something like `ProcessData` and test.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij that actually worked, I think VBA might have a syntax `Go` which might be in conflict with the sub name, hence the error. Changing the sub name to something else worked fine.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Go` is a reserved word according to http://www.audeser.com/vba-reserved-words/

Any uses of reserved words can have unitended consequences. Suggest changing the name of your sub to something else, for example as @ shrivallabha.redij stated `ProcessData`